# Как связать (checked) элемент checkbox и элемент строки li? ЧТобы на выходе строка с текстом равным тексту checkbox можно было изменить

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, веб-программирование

Как сравнить текст поля input checkbox и строки списка li, и изменить в итоге тот li который соответсвует строке input выделенного checkbox?

```
jQuery(function($){

// start ajax 
    $('#filter input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');


        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // 
            type:filter.attr('method'), // 
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').css('opacity', '1').text('Загрузка...'); 
                // 
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').css('opacity', '0');; // 
                if($(".checkbox:checked").length == 0) {
                                $('#response').empty(); 
                          } else {
                                $('#response').html(data); 
                          }
                    }
                    });
        return false;
                    });
//end jquery ajax

    });
// end 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".checkbox").click(function() {

        var checkBoxes = $(this);

        checkBoxes.attr("checked", !checkBoxes.attr("checked")); // fix checked state

        var li = $(".usage-product-list li");

             if (checkBoxes.attr('checked') == 'checked') {

                 for (let el of li) {

                      if(el.innerText == this.parentElement.innerText) {

             el.style.color = 'red';
                };
                 };
   };
    });                 
});
```

В итоге элемент списка применяет стиль color - red и сразу же его сбрасывает.
Так-же если удаляю условие if (checkBoxes.attr('checked') == 'checked') то результат такой-же, как-будто условие не принимается.

```
   <label>
<span></span>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="imya_checkboxa"/>
Название чекбокса
</label>
```

Comment: установите соответствие каким-либо другим способом, а не через `html()`

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать... Добавьте адекватный, воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Отредактировал код, необходимо чтобы элемент списка при включенном чекбоксе строка которого совпадает с тем что указано в label чекбокса изменял стиль

Comment: Ну конечно будет сбрасывать, у вас же при клике происходит 2 события - повторный запрос и выделение, естественно на запрос нужно больше времени поэтому на кароткое время цвет меняется, пока элементы опять не изменятся. Откройте панель разработчика и посмотрите на вкладку Network так там увидите запрос )

Comment: Код применения цвета, нужно вставить в первый код после получения данных от  akax

Comment: Код применения цвета начиная с условия if или полностью код из функции клика?$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
, я попробовал без функции клика вставить код под строку $('#response').html(data);  не работает. Вообще перестал подсвечивать. Естественно я заменил this на переменную .checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, это не то что бы правильно, но можно:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function () {
    let li = $(".usage-product-list li");
   if(this.checked) {
     for (let el of li) {
       if(el.innerText == this.value) {
             el.style.color = 'red';
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Работает, но сразу пропадает установленный стиль. Элементы списка находятся в результате AJAX выдачи.

Comment: Тоесть при новом запросе пропадает выделение ?  Ну это и понятно, так как элементы там сменяются, для полноты картины нужен код и более подробное описание где что и как

Comment: я обновил код сверху. Не то чтобы при новом, он при клике по чекбоксу, выдаёт мне результаты поиска в которых имеется список, по которому сверяется label с li , и подсвечивает нужный li на момент клика. и пропадает стиль сразу.